# Does each block save a copy of a Storage item?

Tags: storage, database

This is what I read from the substrate storage docs: https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/storage/

> Runtime storage allows you to store data in your blockchain that is
> persisted between blocks and can be accessed from within your runtime
> logic.

Does this mean every single block saves a copy of this data? If true, isn't it a waste of resources?
I'm trying to implement a public note system where everyone's note is saved on the blockchain. Should I use this Storage Runtime? If not, what should I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The underlying mechanism is not copying. At any given block, non-archive nodes need to know only one value for one storage item. Even when the node keeps the trace of the historical values, it does it super efficiently by using a kind of a Merkle Trie structure. In designing dApps, you store those sensitive data on the blockchain that could be disputed in the absence of a consensus mechanism. The very obvious example is people's account balances. You can however use that storage for anything but it wouldn't then be a good use of that expensive resource.In your example, if that public note would be an assertion of something that people shouldn't be able to change in a backward way, meaning claiming that their note at that time was a different thing, then it should go to the runtime storage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: What do you mean by `. In designing dApps, you store those sensitive data on the blockchain that could be disputed in the absence of a consensus mechanism.`? When you say on the blockchain do you mean as inherents or as transactions?

Comment: @Purple_Turtle I meant as storage items (in substrate architecture) which keep the state of blockchain. Whatever happens on-chain impacts the state.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to implement a public note system where everyone's note is saved on the blockchain. Should I use this Storage Runtime? If not, what should I use?

Saving everything on-chain is indeed wasteful.
A simple trick is to only save the *hash* of your data on chain and out source the availability of the data itself.

Substrate recently introduced (not live yet) *Preimage* for that exact reason:

> The Preimage pallet allows for the users and the runtime to store the preimage
> of a hash on chain. This can be used by other pallets for storing and managing
> large byte-blobs.

Until then your best bet is probably *IPFS* which addresses data via its hash as well.
PS: NFTs in Ethereum also use that instead of storing the whole image on-chain.